# Integral of f.g is zero

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ , I know that if $\int_{\Omega}{fg}=0$ for all $g \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ then $f=0$ almost everywhere

Now what if $g\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ ? Will I get $f=0$ everywhere??

Comment: What is $\int_\Omega fg$ if $f$ is zero except at one point? You'd have to match against distributions to detect that

Comment: Do you mean that I can obtain f=0 in distribution sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you can not get better than what you've already got.
Indeed, since 
\begin{equation} C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subseteq H_0^1(\Omega)\end{equation}
you obtain that $f=0$ almost everywhere.
But $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and so it is defined almost everywhere.

Trivially you can try to take the function
\begin{equation}f(x)=0\quad \forall x\in\Omega\backslash K\end{equation}
\begin{equation}f(x)=c\quad\quad \text{  on  }\quad K\end{equation}
where $K$ has measure $=0$

Comment: Thanks,also I would like to know, if I have found divf=0 in weak sense ,can some regularity conditions on f give the strong divergence?